# Reduction of sparse features for machine learning

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering, sparse

I'm trying to use a 1D histogram as a feature for machine learning. A histogram instance can be very sparse and the range of its bins is theoretically unbounded. Moreover it is expected that non-zero values for one instance would be grouped together with some holes between. On the other hand machine learning algorithms generally expect dense features with constant number of parameters.

The problem seems to be quite similar to transforming text in the bag-of-words representation to a dense low-dimensional feature space.

An obvious approach would be to transform the sparse vector into a dense one. I've came across several suggestions for solving this problem:

- dictionary learning
- semantic hashing
- SparsePCA
- random projections

What would you recommend and why?

Comment: Are you saying that the feature vector is sparse but there are clusters of non-zero elements? In that case histogram can be approximated by a few gaussians. Your new feature vector will be the position, amplitude, and width.

Comment: @Bohumir: Saw your question after posting a similar question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145771/classifier-with-variable-number-of-features  Did you figure out any way of solving this?

Comment: @alex-i Thanks for a tip. I havent't considered Random Forests at all. Unfortunately, I didn't continue on this problem since I asked the question above.

Comment: In place of a histogram, maybe a density eztimate, maybe look into splines? or logspline density estimation.